# Realizar Backup y Restore de Sqlite a la raiz

Tags: android, android-sqlite

La cosa es que en la versión anterior de mi aplicación, realizaba un backup y restore de mis datos guardados en una base de datos sqlite. Esta copia y respaldo se realizaba en la `sdcard` sin ningún problema con `File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();`.

La duda es que he cambiado de móvil y este no lleva tarjeta `sdcard` y
no se como realizar la copia de dicha base de datos. Son bases de
datos muy pequeñas así que no me importa que esta se guarde
directamente en la raíz del terminal pero no se como realizar el
backup ni el restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que preocuparte. Si se trata de un dispositivo sin posibilidad de insertar tarjetas microSD la llamada a `getExternalStorageDirectory` te devuelve la ruta a lo que se denomina el "almacenamiento compartido" (shared storage), aunque no sea externo o extraíble:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory()

> Note: don't be confused by the word "external" here. This directory
>   can better be thought as media/shared storage. It is a filesystem that
>   can hold a relatively large amount of data and that is shared across
>   all applications (does not enforce permissions). Traditionally this is
>   an SD card, but it may also be implemented as built-in storage in a
>   device that is distinct from the protected internal storage and can be
>   mounted as a filesystem on a computer.

Traducción:

> Nota: No se confunda aquí con la palabra "externo". Puede pensar en
>   este directorio como un medio o almacenamiento compartido. Es un
>   sistema de archivos que puede contener una cantidad relativamente
>   grande de datos y que es compartida por todas las aplicaciones (no se
>   imponen permisos). Tradicionalmente ha sido una tarjeta SD, pero
>   podría implementarse como un almacenamiento interno diferente al
>   almacenamiento interno protegido y que podría ser montado como un
>   sistema de archivos en un ordenador.

Para diferenciar si es de un tipo u otro hay que usar `isExternalStorageRemovable`: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#isExternalStorageRemovable()